# How do add a line to msys.bat:

Tags: windows, batch-file, theano

I am given the following advice on how to resolve an issue and i have no idea how to do that in windows

Add the line to the beginning of msys.bat:

call “c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\vcvarsx86_amd64.bat”

it comes from a guide stating :

```
If you get this error while using Theano:

nvcc : fatal error : Cannot find compiler ‘cl.exe’ in PATH

Add the line to the beginning of msys.bat:

call “c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\vcvarsx86_amd64.bat”
```

I adjusted it since i used a different version of visual studio, still i get the same mentioned error message.

Comment: open `msys.bat` with Notepad (right mouse button, "Edit"), add the line, save and close. Done.

Comment: I did download the msys thing in a random folder and edited the .bat file accordingly. That cannot be all since it does not work :(

Comment: I'm quite sure the errormessage you get is not "it does not work". Be precise. When you say "it does not work", you'll get "well, then something is wrong". from us. What does `dir "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\vcvarsx86_amd64.bat"`say?

Comment: Revised the orgional question. I am sorry for being not precise

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this?
Obviously in whatever path `mySys.bat` is located. Feel free to backup `mySys.bat` just to be careful.

```
>> mySysTemp.bat echo call "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\vcvarsx86_amd64.bat"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%G in (mySys.bat) do (
    echo %%G
) >> mySysTemp.bat
del mySys.bat && ren mySysTemp.bat mySys.bat
```

This just echo's your line into a dummy file, copy line by line `mySys.bat` into the dummy file, then delete `mySys.bat` and rename the dummy file to replace it.